# Q matrix for the reprojectImageTo3D function in opencv

Tags: opencv, depth, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, disparity-mapping

I am doing a project in opencv to detect obstacle in the path of a blind person using stereo calibration. I have calculated the disparity map correctly. Now to find the distance of obstacle from the camera, I want its 3D coordinates [X,Y,Z] , which I am guessing can be found by reprojectImageTo3D(), but I dont have the Q matrix to use in this function because the Q matrix I am getting from stereoRectify() is coming null probably because I used pre calibrated images. Although I do have the inrinsic and extrinsic parameters of my camera.
So my question is that how can I manually create the Q matrix to directly use in the function reprojectImageTo3D(), if I know the focal length, baseline and everything else about my camera? What is the basic format of the Q matrix?

Comment: A brief discription of the 3D reconstruction for stereo vision is given below in the following picture. You can get the **Q matrix** and have a better understanding of it from the process. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrDRD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrDRD.jpg)

Comment: @GavinGao what about going from rectified to unrectified coordinate system ?

Comment: @Pedro77 It is the inverse process.

Answer (score 28):

The form of the Q matrix is given as follows:

[image: Q Matrix Image]

In that image, *c<sub>x</sub>* and *c<sub>y</sub>* are the coordinates of the principal point in the left camera (if you did stereo matching with the left camera dominant), *c'<sub>x</sub>* is the x-coordinate of the principal point in the right camera (*c<sub>x</sub>* and *c'<sub>x</sub>* will be the same if you specified the `CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY` flag for `stereoRectify()`), *f* is the focal length and *T<sub>x</sub>* is the baseline length (possibly the negative of the baseline length, it's the translation from one optical centre to the other I think).

I would suggest having a look at the book [*Learning OpenCV*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do) for more information. It's still based on the older C interface, but does a good job of explaining the underlying theory, and is where I sourced the form of the Q matrix from.

Comment: good work. if you can mention the way to calculate the Q matrix

Comment: Hi, I know that cx and cy are measured in pixels. What is the unit measure of f and Tx?

Comment: @Employee : f is in units pixels of pixels. Tx is in metres (or millimetres)

Comment: Extra paranthesis after Tx

Answer (score 5):

if you want to create directly Q matrix:

```
cv::Mat Q;
Q.at<double>(0,0)=1.0;
Q.at<double>(0,1)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(0,2)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(0,3)=-160; //cx
Q.at<double>(1,0)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(1,1)=1.0;
Q.at<double>(1,2)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(1,3)=-120;  //cy
Q.at<double>(2,0)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(2,1)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(2,2)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(2,3)=348.087;  //Focal
Q.at<double>(3,0)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(3,1)=0.0;
Q.at<double>(3,2)=1.0/95;    //1.0/BaseLine
Q.at<double>(3,3)=0.0;    //cx - cx'
```

But you should calibrate both cameras and then get Q matrix from cv::stereoRectify. Be carefull, read Q matrix as double values.

Comment: Where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: This QMatrix is the output of the process called "Calibration"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Q.at<double>(3,2) = -1.0/95` for the T_x coordinates

Comment: How do you get `Q.at<double>(2,3)=348.087;  //Focal` value?