# Convert between MATLAB stereoParameters and OpenCV stereoRectify stereo calibration

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I wish to convert a MATLAB stereoParameters structure to intrinsics and extrinsics matrices to use in OpenCV's stereoRectify.

If I understood http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html and http://mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/stereoparameters-class.html ,  stereoParameters.CameraParameters1 and stereoParameters.CameraParameters2 store the intrinsic matrices and the other members of stereoParameters the extrinsic ones.

I think I got this mapping

Intrinsics:

- cameraMatrix1 = stereoParameters.CameraParameters1.IntrinsicMatrix'
- cameraMatrix2 = stereoParameters.CameraParameters2.IntrinsicMatrix'
- distCoeffs1 = [stereoParameters.CameraParameters1.RadialDistortion(1:2), stereoParameters.CameraParameters1.TangentialDistortion, stereoParameters.CameraParameters1.RadialDistortion(3)]
- distCoeffs2 = [stereoParameters.CameraParameters2.RadialDistortion(1:2), stereoParameters.CameraParameters2.TangentialDistortion, stereoParameters.CameraParameters2.RadialDistortion(3)]

Extrinsics:

- R = stereoParameters.RotationOfCamera2'
- T = stereoParameters.TranslationOfCamera2'

Is that correct, so far?

Still, I can't see how to get

- R1 (3x3)
- R2 (3x3)
- P1 (3x4)
- P2 (3x4)
- Q (4x4)

matrices from the rest of stereoParameters.

Is there an existing converter I can use, and if not, what are the formulas?

Comment: I found a formula for Q at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28317841 .

Comment: I want to do the opposite and convert from OpenCV to Matlab yml files. Have you found a conversion? Anything could be helpful at this point.

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out, both **camera matrices** need to be **transposed** due to a different notation in MATLAB

[image: MATLAB Camera Intrinsic Matrix]

and OpenCV

[image: OpenCV Camera Intrinsic Matrix]

The same applies for the rotation matrix and the translation vector between the cameras: `stereoParams.RotationOfCamera2` and `stereoParams.TranslationOfCamera2` need to be **transposed** in order to obtain OpenCV's **R** matrix and **T** vector.

(Quick validation: R should be close to an identity matrix if the cameras are almost parallel and the first element of T should match your baseline between the cameras in millimeters.)

OpenCV's **distortion coefficient vector** is composed of MATLAB's two tangential distortion coefficients followed by the two radial distortion coefficients.

That said, I was able to **compute correct R1, R2, P1, P2 and Q** using `(R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, leftROI, rightROI) = cv2.stereoRectify(leftCamMatrix, leftDistCoeffs, rightCamMatrix, rightDistCoeffs, imageSize, R, T, None, None, None, None, None, cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 0)`

Note that for data type reasons, the disparity values obtained using OpenCV's stereo matcher need to be **divided by 16** and the coordinates in the 3d point cloud returned by `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D` need to be **divided by 64 to obtain metric values**.

(Quick validation: when grabbing the coordinates of the same object in the rectified left and right image, the y-coordinates should be almost equal and you should be able to compute the object distance in meters with f*B/(x_right-x_left)/1000 with f being a combined focal length of a virtual camera in Q and B the baseline in millimeters.)

Comment: Thanks for this, but can you elaborate on the divide by 16 and divide by 64 elements of this comment? This is the only part I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: I think the order of Tangential and Radial should be reversed in your answer. Check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Comment: @RakshitKothari what do you mean? The order in the function's parameters is R, T just like above?

Comment: OpenCV's distortion coefficient vector is composed of MATLAB's two tangential distortion coefficients followed by the two radial distortion coefficients. I think you need to reverse that statement to two radial coeffs followed by two tangential coeffs.

Comment: Sorry for comment this answer, but I try your answer and It work exactly fine except the distortion coefficients. What @RakshitKothari says is right, Distortion vector OpenCV started by two radial coefficients followed by two tangential coefficients. You may wanna edit that section so future reader like me didn't make a mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stereoRectify` function in OpenCV to obtain R1, R2, P1, P2, Q given cameraMatrix1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs1, distCoeffs2, R & T.

In C++ it would be

`cv::Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
 cv::Rect validRoi[2];
 cv::stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 0, imSize, &validRoi[0], &validRoi[1]);`

One important thing to note is that **the matrices cameraMatrix1, cameraMatrix2 and R need to be transposed when copying them from their MATLAB counterparts.**

(I put this in bold as it cost 2 days to figure out why my rectification wasn't working when I converted it from MATLAB to C++ OpenCV)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317841 gives the formula for the Q matrix:

[image: Q formula]

Tx is from matrix T. cx, cy and cx' are from the camera matrices. f is some sensible combination of their x and y focal lengths.

Still dunno how to get P1, P2, R1 and R2 though. Anybody?

Comment: what do you mean by sensible combination?

Comment: @kevinkayaks: For example, (fx + fy) / 2. Can you suggest a better way to get f?

Comment: I'm not sure either. I'm very interested in more information about getting from matlab to cv2 calibration if you have learned anything more.