# Stereo calibration from MATLAB to OpenCV

Tags: python, matlab-figure, camera-calibration

I need to perform a Stereo Calibration and the MATLAB tool is for sure more user friendly than OpenCV.

The problem is that in the script I have to use they call a `file.npz` with the calibration parameter. How can I convert the MATLAB output into such a file?

Comment: So, you know how to make it work in matlab? Also I guess you are referring to this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

Comment: yes I can use the matlab tool and yes the file.npz would be written with savez

Comment: You don't provide any information about how exactly is the MATLAB output or what have you tried so far. Maybe you can convert `npz` file to format you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply exported the MATLAB calibration matrices as a string using `mat2str()` and pasted them in numpy using `np.matrix("string")`. Maybe it would better two write a script for this, but for a few matrices it was all right.

Then you can simply export the numpy variables using `np.savez_compressed("filename.npz", variable1=variable1, variable2=variable2,...)` with names matching your subsequent scripts.

Note that [**MATLAB and OpenCV use different notations**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651936/convert-between-matlab-stereoparameters-and-opencv-stereorectify-stereo-calibrat/50925828#50925828) and therefore you may need to **transpose the camera matrices, R and T**!