# obtaining Q matrix from matlab stereoparams

Tags: camera-calibration, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I am working on 3d image reconstrcution using stereo camera. I started with opencv 3.2 and visual studio. I was unable to correctly register two point clouds from two scenes with an overlap correctly. So, I have my doubt on the Q matrix obtained from camera calibration process. So I did the camera calibration using the matlab calibrator app. I want to manually create the Q matrix from the calibration parameters obtained from matlab and then use it in opencv. I found from  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374970/q-matrix-for-the-reprojectimageto3d-function-in-opencv) how to create a Q matrix. Now the problem is i don't know the focal length i should use in this matrix. Matlab provides the calibration parameters in a [stereoparam](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/stereoparameters.html) object which contains camera parameters for both camera sensors separately. So i have fx and fy from camera1 and fx and fy from camera2.  So how do i obtain a single focal length for the stereo camera?

Answer (score 0):

As reported [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/camera-calibration.html), *fx* and *fy* are expressed in pixels.

**F**, the focal length in world unit (typically in millimeters) can be computed as

**F** = *fx* * *px* or **F** = *fy* * *py*,

where *px* and *py* are the size of the pixel along x and y, respectively.

In particular,

*px* = image width [pixel] / image sensor width [mm]

*py* = image height [pixel] / image sensor height [mm].

Answer (score 0):

This is the Q matrix aka reprojection matrix

[image]

Since you have the camera intrinsic matrix and extrinsic matrix, then just fill it in accordingly.

Take note the Tx should be in mm.